# TreeViewer Expand-/Collapse-ToLevel Bug

Tags: java, swt, treeviewer

I have a TreeViewer whose items I am trying to expand or collapse one level.
My TreeViewer contains items that have the same name.
For example:

```
Node 1
  -> Node A
      -> Node B
         -> Node C
Node 2
  -> Node A
      -> Node B
         -> Node C
```

Even if I select the second Node A to expand or collapse, it will still expand or collapse the first Node A.

My code for expand is:

```
ITreeSelection selection = (ITreeSelection) tree.getSelection();
TreeNode selectedItem = (TreeNode) selection.getFirstElement();
tree.expandToLevel(selectedItem, 1);
```

My Code for collapse is:

```
ITreeSelection selection = (ITreeSelection) tree.getSelection();
TreeNode selectedItem = (TreeNode) selection.getFirstElement();
TreeNode[] children = selectedItem.getChildren();
if (children != null) {
    for (TreeNode child : children) {
         tree.collapseToLevel(child, 1);
    }
}
```

What can I do so that the TreeViewer expands and collapses the right selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure that the `equals` method for different objects with the same name in the tree does not return `true`. The tree viewer will not be able to locate the correct tree items if `equals` returns true for two different objects. As always you must make `hashCode` compatible with the equals implementation.

If you can't fix the `equals` method in the objects you can use `IElementComparer` to create a special compare for the tree viewer. Use `TreeViewer.setComparer` to set the comparer for the tree.